# Can't convert array to struct that contains pointers

Tags: c++

I'm writing in c++, windows.

I have a struct that contains a pointer inside, now when I'm trying to convert any array to my struct - it fails to assign the pointer to the data.

e.g.

```
typedef struct {
int header;
int* ptr;
} Test;

int main()
{
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
Test* t = (Test*)&arr;

// t->header will be 1, but t->ptr will be unreadable data - {???}
return 0;
}
```

When I'm changing ptr to be an array (int ptr[];) it's converted as expected.

I'm getting a byte array, containing a huge amount of data, I would like to convert it to a struct, for convenience of access. The data consists of a header, and an array of another struct. That's why I tried to convert it to a struct that contains a header, and a pointer to another struct - which I would like to assign to the head of my byte array, right after the header

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect this to work. What is your goal/what is the actual problem that lead you to try this?

Comment: what you see is to be expected. You cant cast like that. `arr` is not a `Test`. Maybe if you explain why your are doing this we can show you a different way

Comment: You could do `Test t; t.ptr = &arr;`. But this would be an odd design choice. This code is very `c`-like.

Comment: I'm getting a byte array, containing a huge amount of data, I would like to convert it to a struct, for convenience of access. The data consists of a header, and an array of another struct. That's why I tried to convert it to a struct that contains a header, and a pointer to another struct - which I  would like to assign to the head of my byte array, right after the header. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: @mich What you describe looks like a serialization problem. Doing serialization in C++ is not that easy since, generally, you cannot just read/write binary representations of objects (contents of their storage). I would suggest looking at some serialization libraries, such as Boost.Serialization.

Comment: @mich, I'm going to be frank here and say that from your question it seems clear that you should learn the basics of how pointers work and the basics of `C++` like what a `struct` and `class` is. I think this knowledge is needed to be able to express what you really want, and to be able to understand the answer.

Comment: Just compare `sizeof(Test)` and `sizeof(arr)`, and then rethink what you expect. In C++, `sizeof` is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is in that you are trying to convert (cast, in terms of C++) one type to another, to be short.

An *object* of your `Test` struct lays out in the memory in such a way:

```
+------------+-------------------------+
| header     | ptr                     |
+------------+-------------------------+
```

Type of the `header` is `int`, while type of the `ptr` is pointer (i.e., address of some place in the memory). I'm drawing your attention: the `ptr` member is not of `int` type. Furthermore, the size of pointer may be **not** equal to the size of integer (what I reflected conditionally on the "picture").

Now, what you are doing:

```
+------------+-------------------------+
| header     | ptr                     |
+------------+-------------------------+
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| arr[0]     | arr[1]     | arr[2]     | arr[3]     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I.e., you are trying to interpret the first N array's members as memory occupied by the object of type `struct Test`. In this example, the first three members. And, like in this example, your *pointer* `ptr` may be initialized by several array's members superposition.

Furthermore, depending on your compiler/architecture the `Test` structure's layout in the memory may actually be "nonlinear". I.e., compiler may insert so called memory-aligning gap between the `header` and `ptr` data-members. So, your task (if I understood it right) is becoming more tricky.

What can you do to solve your task? I'm not sure that I understood what are you doing. I.e., the application side of your issue. So, I may not imagine what to suggest as a resolving. In any case, the types casting is a low-level feature of the C++ which needs to be used very carefully, with a deep understanding of how it works.